# Set current parse user name after login

Tags: android, parse-platform

I use Parse to build user profile.
Is there anyone know why there is no update on server ROW in Parse?

Code:

```
String parseSessionToken = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getSessionToken();
Log.d("ParseUser.getSessionToken", parseSessionToken);

ParseUser.becomeInBackground(parseSessionToken, new LogInCallback() {
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (user != null) {
            // The current user is now set to user.
            Log.d("ParseUser before getUsername", user.getUsername());
            user.setUsername(stringUserName);
            Log.d("ParseUser after getUsername", user.getUsername());

        } else {
            // The token could not be validated.
            Log.d("ParseUser after fail", e.toString());

        }
    }
});
```

Log:

```
04-27 02:30:21.730      677-677/com.di D/ParseUser.getCurrentUser objectID﹕ cUCPqKIV4HQe892eamTP0Ocyv
04-27 02:30:23.450      677-677/com.di D/ParseUser before getUsername﹕ h3@msn.com
04-27 02:30:39.100      677-677/com.di D/ParseUser after getUsername﹕ h3
```

Parse.com still keep String in old data. (I have reloading)
[image]

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the username you need to call the save method. You can use the below method;

```
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
parseUser.setUsername(stringUserName);
parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (null == e) {
            // report about success
        } else {
            // report about error 
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this helps;

Regards.